# Git - How to make custom alias function always available?

Tags: bash, git, shell, alias

I have a script that I've made that creates a repository locally, creates first commit and creates the remote repo. Here it is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
function create-repo {
    inside_git_repo="$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)"
    # check if we already inside a repository
    if [ "$inside_git_repo" = true ]; then
        echo "Error: It is not possible to create a repository inside another one"

    else
        #check if the name of repository is not null
        if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
            echo "Error: Missing one argument (Repository name)"

        else
            #creating repository folder
            echo "Repo will be created with the following name: $1 "
            mkdir "$1"
            cd "$1" || exit 1
            echo

            #Create a README.md file to push to remote
            echo "# $1" >> README.md
            echo

            #initializing repo
            git init
            echo

            #staging and commiting README.md file
            git add README.md
            git commit -m "first commit"
            echo

            #username in github
            username="alanwilliam"

            #secret token of github API
            token="PUT HERE YOU SECRET TOKEN"

            #json that will be sent to github API
            json="{ \"name\":\"$1\" }"

            #Curl command that does the magic to create the remote on github
            curl --user "$username":"$token" --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$json" https://api.github.com/user/repos
            echo
            echo
            echo

            #adding remote and pushing
            git remote add origin https://github.com/alanwilliam/"$1".git
            git push -u origin master

        fi
    fi
}
```

This code is working just fine - it is perfect for me. I've put it inside a file called `.custom_aliases` and it worked. However, in order to git detect this file and make the command available, every time that I open git bash, I need to type
`source ~/.custom_aliases` to be able to use the command in script, which is annoying.

Is there a way to make it always available, so I don't have to type the source command every time I open git bash?

Comment: Add your source line to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Due to bugs in the `if` statements, the function will 1. fail to detect that you are already in a repository, and 2. start off with an error `[mydir: command not found` whenever you invoke it with an argument `mydir`. Consider running it through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: hey guys, thanks for the info. As fredrik said i changed to .bashrc and it worked fine, solved my problem. @thatotherguy, thank you for the link, i've pasted the code and indeed it had a lot of erros, i've fix then and will edit my question.